# socket - Android client - Java server PC gets stuck

Tags: java, android, sockets, communication

Well, this is my second post and I'm going through such a big problem with socket communication TCP/IP, between android client and a java server application  running on a PC.

What I try to do is send a string when I press a button from my client application to the server and then get an answer back to my client application as many times as I wish, this result is shown in a `TextView` of my client.

The problem occurs when I try to connect to the server with my client application, the connection is performed successfully, but when I press the button and send the data, the client application gets stuck and the only way to show a result is stopping the server application. Please, I need help! I'm new to Android. Thanks.

This is the simple server code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ServerSocks {

private static ServerSocket myServer;
private static Socket myClient;
private static String msj_ToServer;

public static void main (String args[] ){

    try {

        System.out.println("Bienvenido:\n");

        System.out.println("Por favor ingresar el nº de puerto de comunicación: ");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String portNumber_str = in.readLine();
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(portNumber_str);
        myServer = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

            if(myServer.isBound() == true){

            System.out.println("Iniciando servidor en el puerto: "+portNumber); 

            } 

            else{

            System.err.println("[E R R O R] : No se pudo crear 'LISTEN SOCKET'");
            System.exit(0);

            }

            while(true){

            System.out.println("Esperando algún cliente TCP en el puerto ["+portNumber+"]...");
            myClient = myServer.accept();

            if (myClient.isConnected()) { // if2

            System.out.println("[D A T A] : El cliente ha sido aceptado IP-CLIENT\n"+""+ "IP Client address: "+myClient.getInetAddress());

            DataOutputStream outClient = new DataOutputStream(myClient.getOutputStream());

            DataInputStream inClient = new DataInputStream(myClient.getInputStream());
            msj_ToServer = inClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Ha1 "+msj_ToServer);

            try{


            if(msj_ToServer.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
            System.out.println("HO "+msj_ToServer);
            outClient.writeBytes("ON");
            outClient.flush();
            break;              

            } 

            }catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             }

            if(msj_ToServer == "B" || msj_ToServer == "b"){

               System.out.println(msj_ToServer);
               outClient.writeUTF("OFF");
               outClient.flush();
               break;
               }

               if(msj_ToServer == "C" || msj_ToServer == "c"){
               System.out.println(msj_ToServer);
               outClient.writeUTF("xd");
               outClient.flush();
               break;
               }

               } // fin while inicio de lectura  */

               } // fin msj1

              } // fin while prueba 3
              }// fin if2


              } // fin while (true) superior

           } catch (IOException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(ServerSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }// fin main 

} // fin clase ServerSocks
```

This is part of the Main.java of my Android client application (I'm probing with the button ("status" button) that is sending a "D" string to the server and the server sends back an "ON" as an answer).

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button ledOnButton;
private Button ledOffButton;
static ToggleButton toggleButton; 
static EditText statusEditText;
private Button status;
static TextView prueba; 

static Socket clientSocket; 
static String data;

static String dato;

static PrintStream os;
static DataInputStream is;
static DataInputStream inputLine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    ledOnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ledOnButton);
    ledOnButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    ledOffButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ledOffButton);
    ledOffButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    status = (Button) findViewById(R.id.statusButton);
    status.setOnClickListener(this);

    statusEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.statusEditText);

    // prueba con textView

    prueba = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Prueba);

} // fin OnCreate

@Override

public void onClick(View arg0) {

    AsyncAction object = new AsyncAction();
    final String salida_dato;


switch (arg0.getId()) {

    case R.id.toggleButton:


        if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {

            object.conexion_socket();


        }

        if (!toggleButton.isChecked()) {

            object.desconexion_socket();

        }


        break;

    case R.id.ledOnButton:


        if ((MainActivity.toggleButton.isChecked())) {

            object.ledOnButton();
        }

        break;

    case R.id.ledOffButton:

        if ((toggleButton.isChecked())) {

            object.ledOffButton();
        }

        break;

    case R.id.statusButton:
```

here i try to send a "D" String to the server

```java
        if ((toggleButton.isChecked())) {


            if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {

                try {

                    final String responseLine;
                    //    String data = "D";
                    //os.write(data.getBytes());
                 os.println("D");


                    while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(responseLine);


                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                MainActivity.prueba.setText(responseLine);
                                os.flush();

                            }
                        });

                        break;


                    }

                    os.close();
                    is.close();
                    clientSocket.close();

                } //fin try

                catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
                }
```

and here the connection is running in background with asynchTasks (i think so)

```java
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {

        conexion_socket();

        ...


    }//fin doInBackground
```

and here is the connection method that i used to create the socket connection

```java
public void conexion_socket(){

        try {

            MainActivity.clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.2.80", 30000);

            try {

                MainActivity.os = new PrintStream(MainActivity.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                MainActivity.is = new DataInputStream(MainActivity.clientSocket.getInputStream());
                MainActivity.inputLine = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));

            } // fin try

            catch (IOException e){

                System.err.println("algo anda al con los i/o ...");

            } // fin catch




        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (MainActivity.clientSocket.isConnected()) {
            MainActivity.statusEditText.setText("OK connection");
        }
    }
```

please if anyone could give a way to do this communication i would appreciate very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(myServer.isBound() == true){
```

This cannot possibly be false at this point. Remove test and the `else` block. You constructed the `ServerSocket` with a port number => it is bound.

```
        else{
        System.err.println("[E R R O R] : No se pudo crear 'LISTEN SOCKET'");
        System.exit(0);
        }
```

Unreachable. Remove.

```
        while(true){
        System.out.println("Esperando algún cliente TCP en el puerto ["+portNumber+"]...");
        myClient = myServer.accept();
        if (myClient.isConnected()) { // if2
```

Once again this cannot possibly be false. You accepted the socket => it is connected. Don't write futile tests.

```
        System.out.println("[D A T A] : El cliente ha sido aceptado IP-CLIENT\n"+""+ "IP Client address: "+myClient.getInetAddress());
        DataOutputStream outClient = new DataOutputStream(myClient.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream inClient = new DataInputStream(myClient.getInputStream());
        msj_ToServer = inClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Ha1 "+msj_ToServer);
        try{

        if(msj_ToServer.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
        System.out.println("HO "+msj_ToServer);
        outClient.writeBytes("ON");
```

Here you are writing bytes but no line terminator. The corresponding code in the client is using `readLine()`, so it will block forever. Add a line terminator to this string.

```
        outClient.flush();
```

Redundant. Remove. `DataOutputStream` is not buffered, and neither is `Socket.getOutputStream()`, so flushing either of them does nothing.

```
        }catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         }

        if(msj_ToServer == "B" || msj_ToServer == "b"){

           System.out.println(msj_ToServer);
           outClient.writeUTF("OFF");
```

Make up your mind. Are you writing bytes, or lines, or the special format used by `writeUTF()`? The corresponding code in the client uses `readLine()`. I suggest you standardize on writing lines for reading by `readLine()`, or `writeUTF()/readUTF()`. You cannot mix them.

```
           outClient.flush();
```

See above. Remove.

```
           if(msj_ToServer == "C" || msj_ToServer == "c"){
           System.out.println(msj_ToServer);
           outClient.writeUTF("xd");
```

See above.

```
           outClient.flush();
```

See above.

```
        MainActivity.clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.2.80", 30000);

        try {

            MainActivity.os = new PrintStream(MainActivity.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            MainActivity.is = new DataInputStream(MainActivity.clientSocket.getInputStream());
            MainActivity.inputLine = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));

        } // fin try
        catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("algo anda al con los i/o ...");
        } // fin catch
```

There is no reason to put these lines of code inside a try block. You're already inside one.

```
    if (MainActivity.clientSocket.isConnected()) {
```

Yet again this test cannot possibly be false at this point. If the socket was constructed, it is connected.

It can however be *null*, due to your incorrectly structured exception handling. The block that follows this should be inside the prior enclosing `try` block.

In general you should get rid of all the interior `try/catch` blocks. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will follow your recommendations and advice and i'll let you know my results!! I'm expecting if i finally get the communication :) thankssss